# 8 bit color in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ansi-colors

I'm playing with ANSI escape sequences and i'm having a rough time with colors.

I've tried with a couple of color palettes from Wikipedia's ANSI [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), and it always happens the same. I create a color with

```
[UIColor colorWithRed: green: blue: alpha];
```

And the result has nothing to do with the supposed colors (i divide each of them by 256), most of them ending up the same. I believe UIColor is not enough and i should use CGColorRef in order for making the translation. Any tips?

[image: this is the result]

The top colors are the "regular ones" and the lower ones are supposed to be the brighter eight, but everything is messed up.

This is how i create the colors:

```
+ (UIColor *) cyanANSIColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f/256.0f 
                             green:187.0f/256.0f
                             blue:200.0f/256.0f
                             alpha:1.00f];
}

+ (UIColor *) brightCyanANSIColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:85.0f/256.0f
                             green:255.0f/256.0f
                             blue:255.0f/256.0f
                             alpha:1.00f];
}
```

And i assign them to each view vía it's

```
backgroundColor
```

property. You can see the cyan colors are wrong (one of them), and most of them look the same. A dark gray shows blue. And none is an int.

Comment: The color values for UIColor and CGColorRef are from 0 to 1, not 0 to 255. Have you tried dividing 255?

Comment: That method will work, something else is wrong. Post some code? Screenshots?

Comment: Are you writing `127.0/255` or `127/255`? The latter will always give 0.

Comment: You're probably dividing 2 integers. Try forcing floating point division.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, i've updated my question with screenshot and code. I don't think the issue is int/float related because they are not always the same, as you can see.

Comment: Can you include the code to set this to a particular view, including your UIColor method, then put an image of the result you are getting, and if possible the colour you are expecting? At the moment there isn't much to go on, if your numbers are right, it should be working (except for dividing by 255, not 256) and your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @ferostar From the wikepedia page, which color scheme are you referencing?  Your cyan looks like it comes from Terminal.app, but your bright cyan comes from puTTY

Comment: @ferostar  I just did a test.  I dropped 2 small views onto a nib and manually set their colors to the values you provided above.  These display colors as expected.  Thus the problem has to be in code you have not yet shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I get when I manually set the colors of two views to the values specified in the question:

[image]

My "normal" cyan (51,187,200) is at the top and the bright (85,255,255) is at the bottom.  But according to the way the colors look my top color matches your bottom color.  Is it possible that you have not drawn the swatches in the correct location, and thus are seeing the background of the view for the cyan?  And that the other swatches are similarly misdrawn?

Answer (score 2):

You need to divide by 255, not 256:

```
+ (UIColor *) cyanANSIColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f / 255.0f 
                           green:187.0f / 255.0f
                            blue:200.0f / 255.0f
                           alpha:1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but this doesn't makes any difference. I'm still having this issue.

Comment: Whilst correct, this wouldn't make a _huge_ difference to the result. 51 / 255 is not much different to 51 / 256

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a view's background color have you tried the Quartz or OpenGL to render each color to a sub-rect of a CGBitmapImageRep or an OpenGL ES view? If you do not subclass the views you are using there is no telling what other drawing might be going on that is affecting the color of each view.